# Errors importing shapely.geometry into QGIS 3.6

Tags: pyqgis, shapely

I got error messages when executing 2nd statement below in python console of QGIS 3.6 (and QGIS 3.8)

```
import shapely

from shapely.geometry import Polygon
```

If I execute the 2nd statement again, there would be no error messages. After the 2nd execution, all the functionalities (Polygon, LineString, ...) used in my python scripts appear working properly.

Is there any way I can avoid the error messages?
(My QGIS 2.18 arrears no problems with shapely.)

The first and last few lines of the error messages are below:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 985, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
Call stack:
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 579, in runScriptEditor
```

The last few lines are:

```
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 130, in <module>
    os.path.join(sys.prefix, "Library", "lib", "geos_c.dll"),
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 50, in load_dll
    LOG.debug("DLL: %r", dll)
Message: 'DLL: %r'
Arguments: (<CDLL 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\bin\geos_c.dll', handle 7fed56b0000 at 0x17fa9160>,)
```

Comment: Works fine for me using QGIS 3.6.2. Although you should be able to use the second line directly instead of also using `import shapely`.

Comment: After spinning my wheel for 2 days, finally I resolved the issue by deleting the folder C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\QGIS.

Comment: Deleting the \Roaming\QGIS folder worked a while, but the very same problems came back after I turned on all my plugins under the Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins - > Installed. At this point I realized the problems may be related to the plugins. I then turned each plugin on/off to test, and eventually found the “Value Tool” plugin was the culprit causing the troubles. After it was turned off, the problems never came back.

Comment: Glad you found the culprit! You should post this as an answer as it could help others with similar problems :)

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar message earlier in the “add comment” section, and was suggested to re-post this as an answer.

Deleting the \Roaming\QGIS folder worked a while, but the very same problems came back after I turned on all my plugins under the Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins - > Installed. At this point I realized the problems may be related to the plugins. I then turned each plugin on/off to test, and eventually found the “Value Tool” plugin was the culprit causing the troubles. After it was turned off, the problems never came back.

The “Value Tool” also affected matplotlib, which became painfully slow by taking minutes just to plot a simple X-Y curve.